# How to stop AngularJS from Binding in Rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angularjs 1.5.3 I have 2 services one service calls Area names, the other calls the details for the Area.
So in my code, I call the first service to get the Area, then I set the ng-init to call the details. This works fine, however angular keeps only the first value for all the rows.

Here is the code;

```
 <tbody data-ng-repeat="area in vm.Areas" ng-init='vm.getDetails(area)'>
    <tr>
       <td class="text-bold">{{area}}</td>
       <td>{{vm.AreaDetails.Employees}}</td>
       <td>{{vm.AreaDetails.Hours}}</td>
       <td>{{vm.AreaDetails.Sales}}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Any ideas on fixing this?
Thanks

Comment: You should avoid using `ng-init` for this. It's an abuse of `ng-init` and decrease your performance drastically. See: [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Try to get your details before you start rendering.

Comment: what does it mean keep the first value? do you really need a ng-init?

Comment: If I have 10 areas, I then get 10 rows, but the details for only the first area is shown 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using ng-init for this. It's an abuse of ng-init and decrease your performance drastically. See: ngInit. Try to get your details before you start rendering eg (pseydo):

```
vm.areas = vm.areas.map(function(area) {
  return area.details = service.getDetails(area);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have the controller iterate over the areas and call `getDetails` for each of them and append the detail to the respective area when they arrive.

The bindings will be along:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="area in vm.Areas">
 <tr>
   <td class="text-bold">{{area}}</td>
   <td>{{area.details.Employees}}</td>
   <td>{{area.details.Hours}}</td>
   <td>{{area.details.Sales}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

The bindings will be updated when the data arrive.

Or you can use a directive with isolated scope, something like the following:

```js
angular.module('yourModule').directive('areaInfo', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      area: '=areaInfo'
    },
    require: "yourController", // conroller where getDetails is defined
    templateUrl: "area-info.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.areaDetails = ctrl.getDetails(scope.area);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="area-info.html">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-bold">{{area}}</td>
    <td>{{areaDetails.Employees}}</td>
    <td>{{areaDetails.Hours}}</td>
    <td>{{areaDetails.Sales}}</td>
  </tr>
</script>
<tbody data-ng-repeat="area in vm.Areas" area-info="area"></tbody>
```

You can even move the `getDetails` method to the directive itself.

Answer (score 0):

@TJ answer is right on the technical part however i think you have a design problem in your code.

If you want to load area and their details you should load all of them in one go.
Instead you'll load them one by one there.

So let's say you have 10 Area and you're Detail service load data from (i suppose) the server : that makes 11 requests : 1 for all area, 10 for details of each area.

So just load all the whole thing in one call to your service (and presumably the server) and perform a simple ng-repeat.